# Opencart Category - Product Layout Issue

Tags: php, css, opencart

I am having a slight difficulty with the layout of my products in category view on the Opencart CMS platform.

I have temporarily deleted all of the css overrides I had in place to check that wasn't the cause of the problem. I am using the correct image sizes set in the store settings and they all maintain the correct aspect ratio if they are enlarged.

The products are to be aligned in rows of 4 on a standard computer screen. Currently they are randomly 'muddled'. This is the excerpt of code relating to the category view.

- category.tpl [Fiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/ua7vdoeL/)
- nico_product.tpl [Fiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/2vznLmem/)

  ```
      $category_page_products_row = nico_get_config('category_page_products_row');
      if (empty($category_page_products_row)) $category_page_products_row = 3;

      include($nico_include_path . '/template/module/nico_product.tpl');
      foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
      <div class="col-md-<?php echo $category_page_products_row;?>">
          <?php nico_product($product);?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
  </div>
  ```

The website with my issue is [HERE!](http://shop.sugarskulluk.com/collections/aw14)

The website is running php 5.5.18 and OC 1.5.6.4

Screenshots of the issue:

[image: Layout Issues]

Comment: Enclose each row of products into a separate `<div class="col"></div>`...

Comment: I have tried this but no solution. Each product is enclosed in a separate `<div class="col-sm-3"></div>`

Comment: Sorry, typo - each **row of products** should be enclosed in `<div class="row"></div>`. Again, `class="row"`. If one row is filled with 4 products, those 4 `<div class="col-sm-3"></div>` all should be inside of one `<div class="row"></div>`. For each row of products... Got it?

Comment: now that is something I overlooked! I notice however that on the official OC 2.0 demo which uses bootstrap 3 they have the following after each row: `<div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>`. They do not have a new `row` dive after every 4 products.

Comment: OK, then the use of *clearfix* div should help you as well ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `col-sm-3` (in group of four) in separate rows (divs with class `row`)

markup should look like

```
        <div class ="row">
            <div class ="col-sm-3">...</div>
            <div class ="col-sm-3">...</div>
            <div class ="col-sm-3">...</div>
            <div class ="col-sm-3">...</div>
        </div> 

        <div class ="row">
            <div class ="col-sm-3">...</div>
            <div class ="col-sm-3">...</div>
            <div class ="col-sm-3">...</div>
            <div class ="col-sm-3">...</div>
        </div>
```

Following PHP code should work to generate such markup.

```
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($products as $product) {
          if ( $i == 0 ) {
            echo "<div class='row'>";
          }
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-<?php echo $category_page_products_row;?>">
            <?php nico_product($product);?>
        </div>
        <?php 
          $i++;
          if ( $i == 12/$category_page_products_row ) {
            echo "</div>";
            $i = 0;
          } 
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes, currently, the markup is all products in `col-sm-3` without row separating every 4. Would you personally know how to change this php code to do this?

Comment: ahhaa you are absolutely right!! This did the trick.. I did slightly modify to make it adaptable to changes in the theme settings but thanks x a million.. i've edited your answer to reflect my final changes

Answer (score 1):

opencarts clearfix solution doesn't work very well as is.

my solution was...

in catalog/view/javascript/common.js

remove everything to do with clear fix (after // Adding the clear Fix)
and replace it with

```
cols1 = $('#column-right, #column-left').length;

if (cols1 == 2) {
  $('#content .product-layout').parent('.row').addClass('type2');
} else if (cols1 == 1) {
  $('#content .product-layout').parent('.row').addClass('type1');
} else {
  $('#content .product-layout').parent('.row').addClass('type0');
}
```

this tells css if your using layouts with sidebars.

then in stylesheet.css add

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .product-layout:nth-of-type(1n+2) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .product-layout:nth-of-type(2n+3) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .type1 .product-layout:nth-of-type(3n+4) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .type0 .product-layout:nth-of-type(4n+5) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .type1 .product-layout:nth-of-type(3n+4) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .type0 .product-layout:nth-of-type(4n+5) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

this will need some altering/finishing depending on how many products you show for each screen size and number of sidebars..

Basically a page with 0 sidebars (.type0) collapses from 4 products per row at full screen (@media (min-width: 1200px)), stays at 4 then 2 then 1.

you can do the same for categories if you have altered opencart to have category images

Comment: Excellent solution @jonF

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you can create a custom class and add it to `<div class="col-sm-3 custom-width">` it will fix all alignment issue Please check the screenshot

```
.custom-width {
width: 20% !important;}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have the same result as your screenshot. However, try the same for the Jewellery page: [Here](http://bit.ly/1AK59iM) It doesn't work.